# Dynamic tfoot drop-down filters are missing certain options with server-side processing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Problem: Dropdown in status column does not show the third option when a default filter is enabled.

I am using DataTables server side processing. In the status column of the table, I have a dropdown in the header, which has three options (all, completed and in process). This dropdown works perfectly when I don't have a default filter enabled. However, by default I need to only show the records which have the status "in process", so I added a default search value for this, which works, but then when I click on the dropdown menu, only 2 options are there: "all" and "in process".

How can I have a default filter enabled AND the correct dropdown?

I have tried googling this but I haven't found any questions which match what I need. I have tried moving the different parts of my code into different places and playing around with **stateSave**, but nothing seems to fix this.

index.blade.php:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div id="tbl" class="col-sm-12">
            <table id="overview" class="cell-border display">

                <thead class="tbl-top">
                <tr>
                    <th>Retourennummer</th>
                    <th>Auftragsnummer</th>
                    <th>Datum</th>
                    <th>Zustand</th>
                    <th>Aktionen</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot class="tbl-bottom">
                <tr>
                    <th>Retourennummer</th>
                    <th>Auftragsnummer</th>
                    <th>Datum</th>
                    <th>Zustand</th>
                    <th>Aktionen</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var startingStatus = 'angelegt';
            var table = $('#overview').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "searching": true,
                ajax: '{!! route('data') !!}',
                "columns": [
                    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'orderNr', name: 'orderNr'},
                    {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                    {data: 'status.status_description', name: 'status.status_description'},
                    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
                ],
                "search": {
                    "search": "angelegt"
                },
                "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'f>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
                "paging": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "language": {
                    "paginate": {
                        "previous": "Vorherige Seite",
                        "next": "Nächste Seite"
                    },
                    "search": "Suche:",
                    "info": "Zeige _START_ - _END_ von insgesamt _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
                    "lengthMenu": 'Einträge pro Seite' + '<br>' +
                        '<select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">' +
                        '<option selected value="10">10</option>' +
                        '<option value="20">20</option>' +
                        '<option value="30">30</option>' +
                        '<option value="40">40</option>' +
                        '<option value="50">50</option>' +
                        '<option value="-1">Alle</option>' +
                        '</select>'
                },

                initComplete: function () {
                    this.api().columns([3]).every(function () {
                        var column = this;
                        var select = $('<select class="myInput"><option value="">alle</option></select>')
                            .appendTo($(column.header()))
                            .on('change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                    $(this).val()
                                );

                                column
                                    .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                    .draw();
                            });

                        /**
                         * Once an option in the drop-down next to status has been selected, you can read the text in
                         * the drop-down
                         */
                        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                            if (startingStatus === d) {
                                select.append('<option SELECTED value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                            } else {
                                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                            }
                        });

                        /**
                         * When clicking on drop-down next to status, the sorting function is not activated
                         */
                        $(select).click(function (e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        });

                        /**
                         * When drop-down is clicked on, search field is cleared. Otherwise search field must be
                         * manually cleared before using the drop-down.
                         */
                        $(select).on('click', function () {
                            table.search(" ").draw();
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I didn't have this problem when I was using client side processing. I don't understand why I am now having this issue with server side processing.

If I need to clarify anything or provide more code, please let me know.

Comment: With `serverSide: true` your data is loaded partially, that's why `column.data().unique().sort()` returns only unique values across the **loaded** part of your data. If you wish to load unique values for your entire dataset, you're going to have to request that from your server (i.e. using AJAX-call from within `initComplete` callback).

Comment: Hey @YevgenGorbunkov. Thank you for replying. I'm quite new to DataTables tbh. I read about using Callback, however I don't completely understand what to do. Can you point me on the way at all?

Comment: In simple terms, the part of your code inside `initComplete: ...` is absolutely useless with `serverSide: true` as it uses locally available data to generate dynamic dropdown options based on that. The problem in your case is that you have only portion of your data (which, essentially, is the trick with `serverSide: true` to boost the performance). So, that above code generates unique options **only** for that portion of the data.

Comment: What will work with server-side processing requires mostly server-side coding, so nobody can help you much without knowing your back end storage type and data structure.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Right, okay. So nothing that I used in **initComplete:** is useful? I mean, the only thing that doesn't work is the dropdown, otherwise it's working okay. Would it be a better idea to hardcode the 3 dropdown options? If not, I really do need to get this working, so I would be happy to provide any information necessary, if you have the time to help me. Sorry, I'm quite new to all this.

Comment: Hardcoding options may work ***if*** your data is static. If you need to populate those dynamically, it requires adjusting your back end and I can't help you much as laravel is none of my strengths.